# How can I insert a bracket on top or below a sum?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I would like to insert brackets around a sum to signal the number of terms inside like we sometimes do in mathematics. I drew a picture:

[image]

The bracket can be either on top or bottom. Is there any way to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Your cited image shows something 1/2 overbracket, half overbrace.  For a pure overbrace, there is `\overbrace{c+d+e+f+...+i}^{8/a}`.  I know there are other questions on this site that pertain to overbraces, unless the symbol you seek to overset is unusual in design.

Comment: I believe that an overbrace is asked for and the similarity to a bracket is just an artifact of the drawing.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\overbrace{c+d+e+f+\dots+i}^{8/a} \quad
\underbrace{c+d+e+f+\dots+i}_{8/a}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I think `\(c)dots` would be more appropriate here. `mathtools` provides the `\overbracket`/`\underbracket` version.

Comment: Just use `\dots`; `amsmath` knows which kind of dots are good for this case.